# <style> Outside of <head> Rendering on Page

Tags: css, html, styles, boilerplate

Using the HTML5BoilerPlate template from Paul Irish and gang (although, I'm not saying that has anything to do with it) and I have some styles inside  tags that are rendering on page. If I move them inside the  they work as they're supposed to work. I've done this before to do some quick editing and have never seen the styles rendered on the page. Here's a sampling of the head code:

```
<!doctype html public "*">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width"> 
<title>Title</title>

<meta name="bitly-verification" content="xxxxxxxxxxxx" />
<meta name="google-site-verification" content="xxxxxxxxxxxxx" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />

<link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="/apple-touch-icon.png" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="css.css" />

</head>

<body>
    <div id="container">
        <style>
        ...
        </style>
    </div>
</body>
```

However, we've found that taking out the container div allows the style tags to work and they no longer show up in the rendered page. What we haven't figured out is why and that's bothersome. Has anyone ever had this issue? Or can anyone give insight as to why this might happen?

Not a deal breaker just more a matter of knowledge. Thanks.

****EDIT: #selector > * was the culprit - aargh! *****

Comment: Are you saying that styles in an external stylesheet are working fine, but embedded styles are being displayed on the web page as text?

Comment: Sorry, I edited the post again to accurately reflect what's happening. The stylsheets work great, but the embedded style tags don't work and also render on the page. However, if we take out the container div the styles work as intended.

Comment: Can you reproduce this using [http://jsbin.com/](http://jsbin.com/)? You can include your `css.css` file inside `<style></style>`, but keep that one in the `<head>` :)

Answer (score 0):

W3Schools state that:

> The style element always goes inside the head section. - [Reference](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_style.asp)

It makes sense that putting the style tag in the body (for whatever reason you might be doing that) would come with some undefined behaviours.

Comment: Well, you might *expect* that it would "come with some undefined behaviours", but in reality it works fine in "all browsers".

Comment: Actually, it was a brain fart... For some reason I forgot about the global selector we had on the container element so all child elements were `display: table-cell;` DOH! Much ado about nothing! Sorry, guys, thanks for humoring me.

Comment: Your quote and the site you've linked to where it came from is nothing at all to do with the W3C.